# Meaning of "card"

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

The following statement is made in *Elements of Statistical Learning*:
"Our loss function can be represented by a K × K matrix L, where K = card(G)." What does card(G) mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality), the number of elements in a set.